# Java MVC Calculator

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have to make a scientific calculator which is based on MVC model but I don't really know how to divide properly my controlers. I thought to make 1 controler for simple operators (+ - / *) 1 for digits (and dot) 1 other for complex operators (cos sin x²) and 1 for =. I don't really know if I'm going to use the proper way.
Can you give me some advices to succeed this projet ?

Comment: It's easier to help if your provide your initial attempt.

Comment: Worry about your controllers last.  First, create the data model for your project.  Next, create the view.  Finally, create the controllers you need.